# is Firebase delete user data extension capable to delete all documents in deleted user subcollections?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I wanna try Firebase extension delete user data.

Say in Firestore I have path like this

```
users/{uid}/inbox/{messageID}
```

and also

```
users/{uid}/posts/{postID}
```

My question is ....

Is Firebase extension delete user data capable to delete all user message documents, and all users posts documents in Firestore ?

from the documentation in [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/delete-user-data), it seems it can only delete the document that has the same uid in the root main collection only for Firestore. am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same documentation you linked:

> Configuration Parameters:
>
> ...
>
> Cloud Firestore delete mode: (Only applicable if you use the Cloud Firestore paths parameter.) How do you want to delete Cloud Firestore documents? To also delete documents in subcollections, set this parameter to `recursive`.

When you install the extension, you should see a prompt for this [parameter](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/delete-user-data/extension.yaml#L136-L149) and answer `recursive`:

```
  - param: FIRESTORE_DELETE_MODE
    label: Cloud Firestore delete mode
    description: >-
      (Only applicable if you use the `Cloud Firestore paths` parameter.) How do
      you want to delete Cloud Firestore documents? To also delete documents in
      subcollections, set this parameter to `recursive`.
    type: select
    options:
      - label: Recursive
        value: recursive
      - label: Shallow
        value: shallow
    default: shallow
    required: true
```

Comment: yup, it works. I have tested. it can delete all docs in its subcollections after I set it to recursive. thank you very much